# How should existing library classes be extended?

Tags: pharo

```
normalize: sum
    | strategy normalizingSum |
    strategy := sum collect: [ :each | each max: 0.0 ].
    normalizingSum := strategy sum.
    ^strategy collect: [ :each |
        normalizingSum strictlyPositive
        ifTrue: [ each / normalizingSum ]
        ifFalse: [ 1.0 / Action subclasses size ]
        ]
```

I want to make the above an instance method rather than having to pass sum into it explicitly. The issue is not so much that I can't make the method or I can't put it into the `Array` class. It is just that coming from functional languages, I find myself adrift on exactly what is expected of me here.

From what I can tell, as a convention most Pharo methods work directly on instances, while in functional languages what one would do is define a function that is analogous to static methods in C#/Java.

One choice is to put the method into a metaclass in Pharo, but Pharo's syntax is poorly suited for this style of programming. It does not for example have the pipe operator which explains the heavy tilt towards instance methods in all the library code that I've observed.

Extending a standard library class by directly putting a method into it feels a bit wrong somehow to me. When it comes time to push the changes to Github how exactly will things go? Putting it directly into the `Array` class feels like it will turn into a versioning nightmare eventually.

Another choice is to inherit from `Array`. This might be fine for the problem I am doing now, but later I want to do a different problem and do not want to share implementations.

Should I put it in a trait and add the trait to the `Array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here comes from the fact that we are only considering one message that your collections should answer: `#normalized`. In your code, the collection `sum` is the object that needs to be *normalized*. Therefore it would be tempting to say `sum normalized`. However, I wouldn't recommend adding `#normalized` to `Array` (or `Collection`) because the logic of your particular *normalization* is not intrinsic to `Array`: it depends on **`Action`**, which looks as a concept that makes sense in the context of your project.

This doesn't mean that you should never extend `Array` with your stuff. It only means that if your extension is not intrinsic, such a decision would require more thought.

In this case what I would suggest is analyzing whether collections like `sum` in your project have any other behavior that is intrinsic to them. In that case, I would consider having a class to represent them and add to this class messages such as `#normalized`, plus any other one relevant to these objects.

Just as an example, let's assume that your class is named `StrategyCollection`. You could define in it

```
strategy
  ^sum collect: [:each | each max: 0.0].
```

where `sum` is now an ivar of your class. Then you could define

```
normalized
  strategy := self strategy.
  normalizingSum := strategy sum.
  ^strategy collect: [:each |
    normalizingSum strictlyPositive
      ifTrue: [each / normalizingSum]
      ifFalse: [1.0 / Action subclasses size]]
```

which, by the way, could be re-written as

```
normalized
  | strategy normalizingSum |
  strategy := self strategy.
  normalizingSum := strategy sum.
  ^normalizingSum strictlyPositive
     ifTrue: [strategy collect: [:each | each / normalizingSum]]
     ifFalse: [strategy class new: sumstrategy size withAll: 1.0 / Action subclasses size]
```

If you have other strategies besides `#max: 0`, you could easily tweak the code above so to make it more general by using `perform:` or having a special subclass of `StrategyCollection` which implements its own version of `#strategy`.

I would also suggest adding a method for the expression `Action subclasses size`. Something on the lines of

```
actionCount
  ^Action subclasses size
```

and then use it in `#normalized`. The expression `Action subclasses size` is fragile and likely to appear in other methods. For instance, if tomorrow you decide to group some subclasses of `Action` under another abstract subclass, the number of subclasses of `Action` would not adapt to such a refactoring. More generally, the behavior of your objects should not depend on the way you organize your code, because that belongs in a meta-level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely make it an instance of `Array` or even better of `Collection` as your code works on anything that can be iterated (and has numbers).

The reason is that it's more clear to use:

```
#(3 5 49 3 1) normalized
```

rather than:

```
SomeMisteriousThirdParty normalize: #(3 5 49 3 1)
```

Additionally, if you have some special collections or other classes they can define their own versions of `normalized` to handle things correctly.

The philosophy of Pharo is that no one can create a perfect environment exactly for your project. Thus it is easy to change the already available libraries to suit your needs.

The way to do this is to use extension methods where *your* package extends some *other* class with a method. This functionality is present in Pharo (and Smalltalk in general) for more than a decade, exactly for this reason when you need to extend another class but version the change together with your code.

While we are on the topic of normalization, it's worth mentioning that there are at least two big Projects that most likely need normalization to do what they are doing. One is Roassal used for data visualization and one is Polymath used for various computations. You may benefit from taking a look at what do they do.

Comment: The way to do extension methods is to do a method in, say Array, and then move it to another package, right? I am also wondering how are name conflicts for extension methods handled in Pharo.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic in general yes. More info: the concept is called "extension methods". Classically the protocol of the method has to start with the name of the package to which it belongs. But in the latest version of Pharo there is the _Calypso_ class browser which makes use of the new code model and allows to define to which packages methods belong without constraining you to the protocol's name. Conflicts are resolved by each load tool independently, but I expect that the newer code overrides the existing one